# Get non SYN/ACK packets of gRPC via tcpdump

Tags: sockets, grpc, tcpdump

I wanted to see just the DATA packets in the underlying transfers in gRPC. I ran the greeter server-client [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/helloworld) application. Both are running on localhost. When I captured traffic on port 50051, I get the following trace (Omitting a few lines for conciseness):

```bash
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo port 50051
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:55:43.756358 IP6 ip6-localhost.58242 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [S], seq 3711036939, win 65476, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3380654929 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:55:43.756379 IP6 ip6-localhost.50051 > ip6-localhost.58242: Flags [S.], seq 60801323, ack 3711036940, win 65464, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3380654929 ecr 3380654929,nop,wscale 7], length 0
...
...
14:55:43.760075 IP6 ip6-localhost.50051 > ip6-localhost.58242: Flags [P.], seq 224:241, ack 396, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3380654933 ecr 3380654933], length 17
14:55:43.760091 IP6 ip6-localhost.58242 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [.], ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3380654933 ecr 3380654933], length 0
14:55:43.760440 IP6 ip6-localhost.58242 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [F.], seq 396, ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3380654933 ecr 3380654933], length 0
14:55:43.760588 IP6 ip6-localhost.58242 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [R.], seq 397, ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3380654933 ecr 3380654933], length 0
```

Note that the above trace has some SYN, ACK, and FIN packets too.
However, when I wanted to extract just the SYN and ACK packets, it gives me no output?!

```bash
$ sudo tcpdump -i lo 'tcp port 50051 and tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) != 0'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I do get the packets back when I reverse the condition:

```bash
 sudo tcpdump -i lo 'tcp port 50051 and not tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack) != 0'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:05:09.644989 IP6 ip6-localhost.58658 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [S], seq 1905191489, win 65476, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3381220818 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:05:09.645011 IP6 ip6-localhost.50051 > ip6-localhost.58658: Flags [S.], seq 3628833616, ack 1905191490, win 65464, options [mss 65476,sackOK,TS val 3381220818 ecr 3381220818,nop,wscale 7], length 0
...
...
15:05:09.649368 IP6 ip6-localhost.50051 > ip6-localhost.58658: Flags [P.], seq 224:241, ack 396, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3381220822 ecr 3381220822], length 17
15:05:09.649382 IP6 ip6-localhost.58658 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [.], ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3381220822 ecr 3381220822], length 0
15:05:09.649768 IP6 ip6-localhost.58658 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [F.], seq 396, ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3381220822 ecr 3381220822], length 0
15:05:09.649929 IP6 ip6-localhost.58658 > ip6-localhost.50051: Flags [R.], seq 397, ack 241, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 3381220823 ecr 3381220822], length 0
```

How do I remove the SYN/ACK/FIN packets from the tcpdump trace?